# split one object to two ones

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a task which I should split a connected object into two split ones.
on right image, at the bottom right of the image the two objects has connectivity which I should cut this side. I need to have two objects for my further processes.

final task is to find the slope of inner surface as in the first picture

you can see the image:

[image]

i want to have something right left this.

Comment: fixed that image for you @Mason. In the future, please do not post links to imagur they expire and go dead, you the picuture upload button.

Comment: So, you have the first figure and want the sencond? Can you describe the problem a bit more in detail?

Comment: I think he has the second image (to the right -connected one-) and wants the first/left image as a result.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson ,stackover flow did let me put image since my reputation is not enough

Comment: in the above the are two images. one in the left and another in the right. the right image is the original image which i should do process on them. i want to split the blower and above object from each other and finally make the left image. if i split these two object i can work on the much easier.

Answer (score 0):

if you assume the object is thiner at the junction, you can apply morphological opening (using the `imopen` function, you need image processing toolbox). On your example this sould work, but it depends on the other cases you need to process.